# How do I separate reads and writes in CodeIgniter to avoid replication lag?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to have some parts of our applications to read form a read-only database, but I don't want to control this from each model, but rather do it on a global level.

How do I separate reads and writes in CodeIgniter to avoid replication lag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per CodeIgniter [Documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html), you can use

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('group_one', TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('group_two', TRUE);
```

to connection to multiple database. 
To use different database you've to use

```
$DB1->query();
$DB1->result();
```

instade of

```
$this->db->query();
$this->db->result();
```

This example is also taken from the documentation.